# How to add CSS file to iphone project in xcode?

Tags: iphone, html, css, xcode

I am working on a web based application for iphone, I have created new `css`file to the project this css file doesn't affect the html file, but when I have uploaded the css file a host  it worked fine and styled the html

What is the problem ?

### edit 1

This the head element .

`css.css` is working fine and is linked to the `html` correctly 
`jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css` is NOT !

Despite the both files exist in the same border

Onotha.com

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
```

### edit 2

This is the `Objective-C` code, I have an exception, I think in the last line of code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    NSString *path= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"  inDirectory:NO];
//  [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]]];

//  NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
//  NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
//  [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];


    // load css styles
    NSString *cssPath   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"css/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" ofType:@"css"];
    NSData *cssData     = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:cssPath];
    NSString *cssString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:cssData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    // load js
    NSString *jsPath   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyJS" ofType:@"js"];
    NSData *jsData     = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:jsPath];
    NSString *jsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];                         

    // compose full html page
    NSString *pageContent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", cssString, jsString, path];
    [webView loadHTMLString:pageContent baseURL:baseURL];

    return YES;
}
```

### edit 3

I got this after using code posted by Srikar
[image: screen shot]

Comment: Please show the `<head>` from your html file or where ever you are linking the css to the html.

Comment: I can assume this is a path problem. can you explain better hoe do you link the file in Xcode?

Answer (score 2):

You can load CSS from local project directory

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

detail info check [this site](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/uiwebview-revisited).

More elaborate code here -

```
// load css styles
NSString *cssPath   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyCSS" ofType:@"css"];
NSData *cssData     = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:cssPath];
NSString *cssString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:cssData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

// load js
NSString *jsPath   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyJS" ofType:@"js"];
NSData *jsData     = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:jsPath];
NSString *jsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];                         

// compose full html page
NSString *pageContent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", cssString, jsString, actualPageMarkup];
[webView loadHTMLString:pageContent baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
```

More info [here](http://joshjustice.wordpress.com/2010/11/01/external-css-and-js-in-a-uiwebview/)

Comment: where to initiate the css path ?

Comment: css file could be present as part of your project files or it could be a url. here i assume you put your css file as part of your project files.

Comment: please, can you show me example how to link your second code to the UIwebview .?

Comment: check my answer. You can do this - `[webView loadHTMLString:pageContent baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have solved this, but I think you have to load in "pageContent" the content of the page instead of the path.
Something like this:

```
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *pageContent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", cssString, jsString, htmlString];
[webView loadHTMLString:pageContent baseURL:baseURL];
```